# Persists react state when navigating to different pages using localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, next.js

In the following code

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(true);
  const handleClick = (path) => {
    if (path === "/about") {
      setTest(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("test", test.toString());
    setTest(localStorage.getItem("test") !== "false");
  }, [test]);
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a onClick={() => handleClick("/about")}>About</a>
      </Link>
      {test && <p>sample text</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd like to change the state of `test` so that the sample text does not render when I click on my About Page and return to the Home Page. But every time the page renders, the `test` state is inevitably reset back to `true` because of my `useState` declaration.

I thought changing the state using `localStorage` might fix the problem, but I realized that I come face with same inevitable state reset problem.

How can I rewrite my code so that after I click on the About Page and return to my Home Page, I permanently change my `test` state to `false` so the sample text does not render?

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/persist-state-h3h8u?file=/pages/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could default the `test` value to `false`, then in the `useEffect` check `localStorage` and update `test` based on that. In addition, I'd also update `localStorage` when the link is clicked rather than relying on the `useEffect` to do it.

```js
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false); // Defaults to `false`

  const handleClick = (path) => {
    if (path === "/about") {
      console.log("I clicked on the About Page");
      localStorage.setItem("test", "false"); // Set `localStorage` value
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check for value in `localStorage`
    const storedTest = localStorage.getItem("test") || "true";
    setTest(storedTest === "true");
  }, []); // Removed `test` from deps array to only run it once

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a onClick={() => handleClick("/about")}>About</a>
      </Link>
      {test && <p>sample text</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, first i start with the value of localStorage if exists,
second i only change localStorage when state changes! look:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(localStorage.getItem("test") || true);

  const handleClick = (path) => {
    if (path === "/about") {
      console.log("I clicked on the About Page");
      setTest(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("test", test.string);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a onClick={() => handleClick("/about")}>About</a>
      </Link>
      {test && <p>sample text</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` probably because it is not recognized outside `useEffect` and it is being used inside `useState`

Comment: React with SSR? localStorage is defined at window object!